# How does a power surge reset a modem?

Tags: current

Yesterday, there was a huge power surge in my area, and I wasn't able to connect to the internet any more.

The reason was that the Wifi modem was somehow automatically reset to its factory configuration. I had to reset it to my settings today to get it working again.

Is this a normal thing? How does it happen?

Comment: Your poor poor modem. I cannot give a concise answer, but I can tell you that your device did not enjoy it.

Comment: It could be worse. http://www.flickr.com/photos/xtl/4072175061/

Answer (score 11):

Often what happens in this sort of situation is not that the surge resets the configuration, but that it's sufficient to flip one bit of the configuration, such that a checksum then fails and the software decides to reset all the config to its factory settings.

Basically, high voltages push high currents, and fast-changing high currents can induce current in adjacent conductive objects, which can create the right conditions for the very tiny and delicate structures which make up non-volatile memory to change state.

Comment: That is about what I would have said also.

Comment: That is my guess as well.

Comment: Good lesson to learn here for those that design electronics, a check-sum probably just allowed a product to save itself from non-standard behavior.

Comment: Yes, better to return to a known-good configuration instead of one of dubious quality that may cause problems.